Searching multiple indexes
I have multiple indexes in Azure search. I would like to create one search that searches multiple indexes. Is this possible in Azure AI Search?

Unfortunately no. You can only perform search in a single index only. You would need to do searches against each index separately and somehow combine the results on the client side.
